# Extra dynamic column in an Action Result in LINQ to SQL

Tags: model-view-controller, linq-to-sql

I'm still feeling new to [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL) and need a pointer on the following.

I have this existing code in my controller which is used in my index view:

```
    var allIncident = _securityRepository.FindAllIncident(userId, SystemType.EI);
    var searchResults = (from s in allIncident
                         where s.IncidentDescription.Contains(searchText) &&
                         s.Site.SiteDescription.Contains(searchTextSite)
                         && (s.Entered >= startDate && s.Entered <= endDate)
                         orderby s.Entered descending
                         select s);
```

This is fine, but I need to add another dynamic column (three actually, but once I know how it's cool). I have a 1-M table called IncidentAction. There are many incident actions to one Incident. So I want to add an extra column that's dynamic that will count the number of Incident Actions for each row in search results.

Where do I start? In SQL I'd just do a `select count as col_name`, but here I'm not sure where it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
    var searchResults = from s in allIncident 
                     join I in AllIncidentActions
                         on a.Id=I.Id
                     where s.IncidentDescription.Contains(searchText) &&
                           s.Site.SiteDescription.Contains(searchTextSite)  && 
                           (s.Entered >= startDate && s.Entered <= endDate)
                     orderby s.Entered descending  
                     select new
                     {
                          a.Id,
                          a.Dsc,
                          ...
                          a.AllIncidentAction.Count
                     };
```

Comment: many thanks, almost there, I need to add a where to the a.AllIncidentAction.Count last expression line, any ideas?

Comment: i.e. a.Incident.IncidentActions.Count where a.SignedOff != true

Comment: @John: I don't understand Correctly please edit your main post with your new statement